# ERROR FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787) Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqlite3

Ando desesperada por encontrar una solución y todo lo que encuentro es con Android Room (que no estoy utilizando y no me sirve... Creo)
Soy bastante novata en la programación y me gustaría saber dónde se encuentra el error:

```
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting idTipoFK=TYP-20f4c0ba-8aa7-47c9-9cd8-19861f93f2dd idUserFK=US-a6c29fe5-3839-40d5-8026-ab0d76c1af0e adjuntoImg=imagen titulo=titulo idEntrada=ENT-d6c47933-c05b-4499-833c-7d2a160f5649 texto=texto fecha=09-12-2019.11:25:28 adjuntoAudio=audio
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1474)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343)
    at dam.proyecto.nasciturus.Database.OperacionesDataBase.insertarEntry(OperacionesDataBase.java:102)
    at dam.proyecto.nasciturus.Actividades.ListarActivity$4.onClick(ListarActivity.java:116)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Esta es mi BBDD:

[image: BBDD]

este metodo que no entraba en la foto

```
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int
             newVersion)    {       
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+
    ConstantesInterfaces.UserID.TABLA_USER);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ ConstantesInterfaces.TypeID.TABLA_TYPE);        
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ ConstantesInterfaces.EntradasID.TABLA_ENTRY);
                    onCreate(db);   
    }
```

Y este es el método que falla:

```
     public void insertarEntry(Entry entrada) {         SQLiteDatabase db = baseDatos.getWritableDatabase();

        // Generar Pk       String idEntrada =
 ConstantesInterfaces.EntradasID.generarIdEntrada();

        ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
        valores.put(ConstantesInterfaces.EntradasID.ID, idEntrada);
        valores.put(ConstantesInterfaces.EntradasID.FECHA, entrada.fecha);
        valores.put(ConstantesInterfaces.EntradasID.TITULO, entrada.titulo);
        valores.put(ConstantesInterfaces.EntradasID.TEXTO, entrada.texto);
        valores.put(ConstantesInterfaces.EntradasID.ADJUNTOIMG,
 entrada.adjuntoImg);
        valores.put(ConstantesInterfaces.EntradasID.ADJUNTOAUDIO,
 entrada.adjuntoAudio);
        valores.put(ConstantesInterfaces.EntradasID.ID_USER,
 entrada.idUsuario);
        valores.put(ConstantesInterfaces.EntradasID.ID_TIPO,
 entrada.idTipo);

        // Insertar entrada
        db.insert(ConstantesInterfaces.EntradasID.TABLA_ENTRY, null,
 valores);

    }
```

Y esta es la insercción que hago que hace que el programa implosione:

```
 Entry entrada = new
 Entry(ConstantesInterfaces.EntradasID.generarIdEntrada(),fecha,
 "titulo","texto",adjuntoImg, "audio"  ,usuario , tipo);
                     OperacionesDataBase db = OperacionesDataBase.obtenerInstancia(getApplicationContext());
                     db.insertarEntry(entrada);
```

Ya sé que en el error, si os fijáis me pone que inserta titulo y fecha mal, eso está corregido, pero quiero ver si alguien por favor me dice cuál es el error.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: No entiendo porque pones esto: `OperacionesDataBase db = OperacionesDataBase.obtenerInstancia(getApplicationContext());` cuando lo puedes poner así: `OperacionesDataBase db = new OperacionesDatabase(getApplicationContext());` Tengo otra duda, ¿Cómo se supone que estas guardando los datos? ¿Con un botón?

Comment: Otra duda, ¿Cómo es el método `generarIdEntrada()`?

Comment: Si compartiste todo como texto, por qué compartes ese código como imagen? :(

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo, ¿Corrigiendo lo del contexto se arregla mi problema?, se guardan con un boton.
El método generar entrada es: public static String generarIdEntrada() {
            return "ENT-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        }

Comment: @Alfabravo, me lo han tenido que editar porque ni si quiera he sido capaz de meter bien el código que ves =(

Comment: ¿Podrías pasarme el proyecto? Así lo veo desde mi ordenador y será más fácil encontrar el error. @Ludaga

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo, claro, dame una dirección o algo donde pasártelo

Comment: francojoelbalsamo@ outlook. com (lo puse separado para evitar inconvenientes @Ludaga